# Is there a way to make a field in Dynamics CRM as one time entry field?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

Basically, what I want is that the user should be able to select the dropdown and not be able to change it after making and saving the selection. So it will be a ***one-time*** entry field.

Below is a screenshot of the field I want to apply this property.

> [image: photo]

So this field has a ***Yes*** or ***No*** selection. And to make the business logic from failing I have to make it a one-time entry field only.

I looked up the form editor for possible things but couldn't find anything that would let me achieve this.

UPDATE #1

Below is my onload function:

```
function Form_onload() {
    var formType = Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType();
    var p = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("opportunityid");
--------------NEW CODE--------------------------------

    if(formType ==2){ //form type 2 means the form is a saved form. form type 1 is new form.

    alert(formType);
    var myattribute = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("var_internal");
    var myname = myattribute.getName();
    if (Xrm.Page.getControl(myname) != null) {
        //alert(myname);
        Xrm.Page.getControl(myname).setDisabled(true);
    }
    }
--------------NEW CODE---------------------------
    if (formType == 1 && p != null && p.getValue() != null) {
        alert('Child Opportunities can only be created by clicking the Create Child Opportunity button in the Opportunity ribbon.');
        window.top.close();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to environment-specific settings in my DEV, I was not able to reproduce what was suggested by *@Eccountable*.  Although, his solution worked in other environments.

*@AnkUser* has a good answer as well but I was looking to shorten the code and make things as simple as possible.

**My solution**

I was able to handle this using **Javascript** on *client-side.* using the XRM toolbox.

In the XRM toolbox, I located the javascript for the opportunity and observed field changes in `formType` when the Opportunity was *New* and when the Opportunity was *Existing*. This variable (`formType`) was =1 when the Opportunity was New and =2 when it was *Existing/Saved*.

Using this piece of information I was able to leverage my Javascript as follows in `Form_onload()`

```
function Form_onload() {
    if (formType == 2) {
        var myattribute = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("internal");
        var myname = myattribute.getName();
        if (Xrm.Page.getControl(myname) != null) {
            Xrm.Page.getControl(myname).setDisabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: JavaScript is client side. No way FLS will work in this situation. If you would have mentioned that users will be able to enter value only in create mode, not on update mode - then this is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

No code solution: I think you could use an Option set with a Yes/No option and a default of Unassigned Value. Then add that field to Field Level Security with "Allow Update" set to No.

[image: Field Level Security with no update]

When updating the FLS field permissions, be sure that the profile is associated with the organization "team" so that all users can see the field:

[image]

Comment: This does not work. I am still able to change options after saving the Opportunity. Also I have made sure I am in the group for which the FSP changes are suggested.

Comment: Are you the system administrator? If yes, then you will be able to bypass this rule. It should work for all other users.

Comment: Basically the group I am in I added that and then tried to create a fresh opportunity, but I am still able to change options.

Comment: FLS is for same permission on an attribute for different users across the records always. So this won’t help in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Arun already gave you an hint how to proceed, I just tried this req on one of my instance.

Create one extra field (dummy field) in my case I call it `new_hasfieldbeenchanged1`
This field will hold data when field is changed. Lock this field (always) and keep this field on form (but visibile =false)

Now you need 2 trigger Onload and OnSave. Below function will do your work. Let me know if this helps.

```
function onLoad(executionContext) {

    debugger;
    var formContext;
    if (executionContext && executionContext.getFormContext()) {
        formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
        //executionContext.getEventSource()
        if (formContext.getAttribute("new_hasfieldbeenchanged1") && formContext.getAttribute("new_hasfieldbeenchanged1").getValue()!=null) {
            if (formContext.getControl("new_twooptionfield")) {
                formContext.getControl("new_twooptionfield").setDisabled(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
function onSave(executionContext) {
    debugger;
    var formContext;
    if (executionContext && executionContext.getFormContext()) {
        formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
        //executionContext.getEventSource()
        if(formContext.getAttribute("new_hasfieldbeenchanged1") && formContext.getAttribute("new_twooptionfield") && formContext.getAttribute("new_twooptionfield").getIsDirty()){
            formContext.getAttribute("new_hasfieldbeenchanged1").setValue((new Date()).toString());
            if (formContext.getControl("new_twooptionfield")) {
                formContext.getControl("new_twooptionfield").setDisabled(true);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The variable I am playing around is - `internal` . Now i don't get what you mean by other fields here. like `new_twooptionfield` , `new_hasfieldbeenchanged1`

Comment: `new_twooptionfield` field in your case will be internal  and `new_hasfieldbeenchanged1` in your case is new field, which will just hold data so that you can enable/disable your internal field based on `new_hasfieldbeenchanged1`  (new field)

Answer (score 0):

There’s no OOB configuration for such custom requirements, but we can apply some script logic.

Assuming this is a **picklist** with default *null* and not a **two-option bool field**, we can use `onLoad` form script to check if it has value & lock it. No need to have `onChange` function.

If it’s a bool field, then it’s hard to achieve. You have to track the initial value & changes made to implement the logic you want. Or through some [unsupported code](https://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/paulnieuwelaar/2011/09/19/No_Default_Value_on_Two_Options_Field_Dynamics_CRM_2011.aspx).

Comment: The post does something different from what I am trying.  IN my case I have to select one of the 2 options and then after saving make the field uneditable

Comment: Also its a `Yes` and `No` field instead of boolean.

Comment: @mishsx some terminology clearance: bool field is same as true/false, yes/no, 1/0, etc bcoz no choice of null. You may need another field to capture user interaction on that field to decide dirtiness or some other complex logic every time.

Comment: Using alert when I am capturing values like alert(attributename); it shows null, true and false.

Comment: I am trying to come up with a logic such that once the opportunity is SAVED, the user cannot alter the values of that field.

Comment: Let me paste my onload function